# Route.delete() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Keep getting this error but can't figure out what is wrong with my delete function. "Route.delete() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]"

```
const playerController = {
      index: (request, response) => {
        Player.find({})
          .then(player => response.json(player))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  },
  create: (request, response) => {

    Player.create(request.body)
      .then(player => response.json(player))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));

  },
  delete: (request, response) => {
    Player.remove(request.params.id)
    .then(player => response.json(player))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
    //console.log('node function');
  }
};


    //- - - - = = = = Routes = = = = - - - - 

    app.get('/players', playerController.index);
    app.post('/players', playerController.create);
    app.delete('/players/:id', playerController.destroy);

    app.all("*", (request, response) => { response.sendFile(path.resolve("./manager/dist/index.html")) });
```

Comment: `app.delete()` points to `playerController.destroy`, but you don't show any code for `playerController.destroy`.   You show code for `something.delete`.

Comment: Yeah that's my bad. I've edited the above code to include it all.

Comment: There's no code for `playerController.destroy`.  Did you just mix up `.delete` and `.destroy`?  Should it be `app.delete('/players/:id', playerController.delete);`?

Comment: Yup I did have that mixed up. So that got my project back up and running, but it still won't actually remove the entry from my DB.

Comment: Not sure what you expect us to help with in that regard.  Would [`Model.findByIdAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) be useful?

Comment: Yep that was it! Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

OK, to wrap this up, there were two issues here:

1. You were using `.playerController.destroy` when you should have been using `playerController.delete`.
2. To remove your item by id, you should be using `Player.findByIdAndRemove()`.